# How to merge multiple images (.GIF) in one with ASP?

Tags: html, image, asp-classic, merge, gif

I have a map of Europe, and what I want to do is have each country of a colour depending of some variables. I display them correctly as separate .gif's, but I'd like to create a unique gif so it can be downloaded as 1 image.

Is it possible to do with ASP?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you looking to create a multi-page GIF?

Comment: it certainly is possible, but is there any reason why you can't use photoshop/gimp to merge them together?

Comment: @Pekka: Imagine, for example, a Risk-type game, and you want to have each country of a different colour depending of its owner. I want to create "the map" as a unique .gif so it can be downloaded to each player's computer.

Comment: @ArcDare How would you paste them together in a way that works - are the country shapes transparent GIFs?

Comment: @LieRyan: I can't use photoshop for this since I want it to be automatic, depending of some variables on my database. Imagine for example what I wrote on the previous comment. I can't create all the combinations, since there are thounsands different. That's why I create them dinamically.

Comment: @Pekka Yep, I have each country as a .GiF in blue, red, yellow... and with ASP I choose wich one to be seen. It works perfect, but it shows like 50 different gifs (one for each country)

Comment: @ArcDare: if that's the case, I would think it would be much easier and better to do it in client-side. Let the users download a static image [sprite sheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29), and then use Javascript to compose the scene. You probably wouldn't want to stitch the image at server-side since that would imply the user downloading the whole image every time the scene changes.

Comment: @ArcDare: additionally, if all the images for each country are the same except for their colors, then you could probably lower the bandwidth even further by colorizing the image on Javascript; although that would probably stretch slower computers so it will be a tradeoff depending on the number of different colors.

Comment: @LieRyan: The solution implementing Javascript is another option, but that's not what I was looking for. 
However, how could I do it with Javacript? I don't understand what you mean with the sprite sheet and how would that create an image.

Comment: @ArcDare: you can simply overlay multiple `<div>`s with partially transparent background on top of each other using absolute positioning, there is no need to produce an "image". A sprite sheet is basically just a single large image that contains many smaller images (in your case, the countries with different colors). When you need a particular image, you "slice" one image from the sheet (with background-position and the div's height/width) and place it on the scene. More about sprites on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8626&lngWId=4

I wrote that back in 2003, it'll do what you're asking with some tweaks, but I haven't touched ASP in at least 5 years :)

The idea is that the script opens a gif, reads out the color palette and re-writes it.  It's currently configured to "adjust" the palette's HSL so that you can get different colored images (e.g. you could adjust a green image to blue or red), but you could just as easily selectively replace individual colors with whatever you want.

The idea then would that you would make each country it's own specific color and then replace that color with whatever you wanted later.  As long as there are <= 256 total colors, you should be fine.

If you want something more complicated, try looking into imagemagick

Comment: Wow that's a completely different approach to my problem! I'll explore it, thank you very much. Let me test it!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing within ASP to do what you want.  You would need some third party component to perform this type of task.